# What is the definition of "allmost all" in probability theory?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, almost-everywhere

Assume $X_1,X_2,\dots$ are identically distributed random variables. Assume $A(X_1,X_2,\dots)$ is an event which depends on the $X_i$. What does it mean to say "For almost all $X_1,X_2,\dots$ we have $A(X_1,X_2,\dots)$"?

Edit: See theorem 2.1 of:  https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1176345637

Comment: I guess it means "for all $i$ except finitely many".

Comment: It usually means that the set of $X_i's$  that don't satisfy $A$  is a set whose measure is zero

Comment: I think this depends strongly in the book of source you read it. In general there is not a unique meaning for "almost all". The most common meaning is "for all except some finite number of cases".

Comment: I added the source which uses the terminology

Comment: In contexts where there is a measure under consideration (e.g., in probability theory), "almost all" means "all except a set of measure zero". The "all but finitely many" meaning is used **only** in many of the contexts where no measure is involved. (Other meanings also occur but far less often.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Almost all" unambiguously means that it happens with probability $1$; contrary to the comments, this doesn't depend on the source, and it doesn't mean that it's true for all but finitely members of a sequence.  The event in the paper you link is more complicated, but here's a more elementary / classic example:

> Let $(X_i)$ be a sequence of i.i.d. random variables with $\mathbb{E}[X_1]< \infty$.  Then for almost all sequences $(X_i)$, $$\frac{\sum_{k = 1}^n X_k}{n} \to \mathbb{E}[X_1]\,.$$

This is the strong law of large numbers, and can be rephrased as: $$\mathbb{P}\left[\frac{\sum_{k = 1}^n X_k}{n} \to \mathbb{E}[X_1] \right] = 1\,.$$